# cronjob is failing -- how to tell it to always run as root?

Tags: server, sudo, cron, letsencrypt

I use LetsEncrypt on my server to renew HTTPS certificates. If I manually log in to my server and execute

```
$ sudo /opt/certbot-auto renew --nginx --quiet --no-self-upgrade
```

then my certificates upgrade and everything is great.

I wanted to make this run as a daily cronjob, so I did:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

and added the lines:

```
# try to renew  "at 00:00 on Every Day of the Week"
0 0 * * 1-7  /opt/certbot-auto renew --nginx --quiet --no-self-upgrade >> /var/log/le-renew.log
```

... howver, this has not been working. I checked the contents of `le-renew.log` and found the following, repeated many times:

```
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>-0001/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.<domain>/fullchain.pem (failure)

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>-0001/fullchain.pem (failure)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.<domain>/fullchain.pem (failure)
```

---

To me, this *seems* to indicate that the cron job is not running as sudo -- if I do not add sudo when manually invoking the command ( first code block in this post ), then the renew fails.

Am I doing anything wrong here? How can I insure the cron job runs with root permissions? Any tips on how I can debug this issue? Like I said, the command runs as expected when I manually SSH in and invoke it with `sudo`, but it does not seem to work right when added as a daily cronjob.

Comment: You should redirect the stderr of that command as well `>> /var/log/... 2>&1`

Comment: Redirects the stderr. Errors are usually logged to stderr, so without that, what you're showing us is likely only partial output.

Comment: @muru great! I've added this to my cronjob, thank you. 

Comment: `sudo crontab -e` edits root's crontab, so you're running as root. The problem has to be somewhere else. I'm not familiar with LetsEncrypt. Is it possible that the problem is related to environment variables? Does this command run if you switch to a virtual terminal Ctrl+Alt+F1 (same but F7 to return), drop to root and then run the command as the root user? FYI, you can change the `1-7` to `*` for everyday of the week.

Comment: Will it work if you put `/opt/certbot-auto renew --nginx --quiet --no-self-upgrade` in a script, make it executable and invoke the SCRIPT with sudo in a terminal, like `sudo /path/to/script.sh` If that works, it suggests another, perhaps simpler solution.

Comment: Dont use 2>&1. The regular output and error output may be mixed beyond recognition. Use 2>>/var/log.err instead. Secondly, as b_laoshi already opted, there are just a few environment variables set when a script is started by cron. You need to ascertain which are required for your update process, put them in a script, then follow Lew Rockwells posting and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue running RKHunter on my server.
Log in as SU and then do Crontab -e you can still point towards users folder but it will run with privileges there.

Comment: this is not a proper answer as it is discouraged to enable root login.